# Performing exact match when comparing variables in SPSS Statistics

Tags: spss

I'm wondering if there's a way for me to perform an exact match compare in SPSS. Currently, using the following will return system missing (null) in cases where one variable is sysmis:

```
compute var1_comparison = * Some logic here.
compute var1_check = var1 = var1_comparison.
```

The results look like this (hypens representing null values):

```
ID   var1    var1_comparison    var1_check
 1      3                  3             1
 2      4                  3             0
 3      -                  2             -
 4      1                  1             1
 5      -                  -             -
```

What I want is this:

```
ID   var1    var1_comparison    var1_check
 1      3                  3             1
 2      4                  3             0
 3      -                  2             0
 4      1                  1             1
 5      -                  -             1
```

Is this possible using just plain SPSS syntax? I'm also open to using the Python extension, though I'm not as familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different approach, using temporary scratch variables (prefixed by a hash (#)):

```
recode var1 var1_comparison (sysmis=-99) (else=copy) into #v1 #v2.
compute Check=(#v1 = #v2).
```

Comment: better do this without changing the original data:   
`recode  var1 var1_comparison (MISSING=-999)(else=copy) into #v1 #v2.   
compute var1_check = #v1=#v2. `

Comment: Agreed! Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is to recreate your example:

```
data list list/ID var1 var1_comparison.
begin data
 1, 3,  3             
 2 , 4, 3             
 3, , 2             
 4, 1, 1             
 5, ,
end data.
```

Now you have to deal separately with the situation where both values are missing, and then complete the calculation in all other situations:

```
do if missing(var1) or missing(var1_comparison).
compute var1_check=(missing(var1) and missing(var1_comparison)).
else.
compute var1_check = (var1 = var1_comparison).
end if.
```

Comment: I think you'll need a third condition where either `var1` **or** `var1_comparison` is missing and the other isn't and so to be equated as a zero for inequality.

Comment: That's a good point @Jignesh Sutar, thanks. I changed the first condition to take care of that.